# Rails - What are the proper 3-way table relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am working on an application wherein I am stuck deciding on a relationship.  The situation is this:

The implemented relationships are:

```
Category has_many Items
Outlets HABTM Categories
```

The problem is that Outlets needs to have many-to-many relationship with the Item model. Now i can implement it simply like:

```
Outlet HABTM Items
```

which will give me a table with `outlet_id` and `item_id` but in that case I am not sure how to find out the list of items for an outlet for one of the categories assigned to it.

I also saw the `has_many :through` example but it also suggests having two foreign keys in the table; I believe that there should be three in this case, `outlet_id`, `category_id`, `item_id`, where in the combination of all 3 will be unique.

I can implement this easily using raw SQL queries but i haven't use any raw queries yet, and want to avoid as much as possible.  How can I properly do this using model relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it simply like :

```
Outlet has_many categories & Category has_many items
```

This way we can get all the `items` for a specific `category` in an `outlet` and also can get all items for an `outlet` through `categories`.